# Tweening / interpolation / easing RGB

Tags: animation

It looks like I'm doing something wrong in my calculations and i can't figure out what :(

I'm working on this LED-strip controller, and I want tweening / easing between 2 colours.

Say we have 255 0 0 (R, current) and 0 0 255 (B, target).

Now when I start the event, it R should run down and B should run up (so they meet at 128 0 128) and then it turns to blue.

I've tried the following;

```
    if (animationcounter < animationlength) {
        for (k = 0; k<3; k++) {
            current_rgb[k] = easeInOutCubic(animationcounter, begin_rgb[k], rgb_2[k], animationlength);
        }
    } else {
        for (k = 0; k<3; k++) {
            current_rgb[k] = rgb_2[k];
        }
    }
```

- Animation length is 120.
- Animation counter gets increased every frame (60 fps, so the animation should run for 2 seconds).
- current_rgb is the current value (array 0, 1, 2)
- target_rgb is the target colour
- begin_rgb is set to current_rgb as soon as i start the animation, as is the counter set to 0.

The easing functions looks like this;

```
///easeInOutCubic(time, begin, changeTo, duration)
function easeInOutCubic(t, b, c, d) {
    return c*t/d + b;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that, when i go from red to red, the RGB value goes from 255 0 0 to 500 0 0 and then pops to 255 0 0 - where I would need it to stick to 255 (as there is no difference between begin and target).

When i go from R to B, B runs up to 255, but R doesn't change (it goes to 255 0 255 and then pops to 0 0 255).

Looks like I'm not subtracting something, but I can't figure it out :(

If this linear function works good then I can start using the quad / cubic easing for smooth effects on the ledstrip.

I'm lost and stuck, everything I try fails and it feels like I'm missing just a very simple point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh.. Figured it out. The change was indded missing a subtraction - the change shouldn't be an absolute value (not target) but total change, so I've changed the function;

```
if (animationcounter < animationlength) {
    for (k = 0; k<3; k++) {
        current_rgb[k] = easeInOutCubic(animationcounter, begin_rgb[k], rgb_2[k], animationlength);
    }
} else {
    for (k = 0; k<3; k++) {
        current_rgb[k] = rgb_2[k];
    }
}
```

to the following;

```
if (animationcounter < animationlength) {
    for (k = 0; k<3; k++) {
        current_rgb[k] = easeInOutCubic(animationcounter, begin_rgb[k], rgb_2[k] - begin_rgb[k], animationlength);
    }
} else {
    for (k = 0; k<3; k++) {
        current_rgb[k] = rgb_2[k];
    }
}
```

Note the **rgb_2[k] - begin_rgb[k]**.

That was it. Rubber ducking sometimes works great!